# Batch file :: if lss is not working properly

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, dos, ping

My code is pretty much self explanatory :

```
@echo off
set /a n=0
:doitagain
set /a n+=1
echo Pinging : 10.0.0.%n%
ping 10.0.0.%n%
if %n% lss 255 goto doitagain

pause >nul
```

but it always pinging 10.0.0.1 so I guess tiny tweak needed here...

Comment: as posted it works.Is it part of if condition or for loop?

Comment: can you use if %n% lss 255( 
echo %n% >>log.txt
goto doitagain)

to check how the flow is going on

quite possible your batch is still pinging and executed that command and it skips to next step

Comment: then  you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: Or just use a `for /L` loop.  `for /L %%N in (0,1,255) do ping 10.0.0.%%N` -- see `for /?` in a console window for more info.

Answer (score 1):

As npocmaka stated in his comment you always need **delayed expansion** when you are working with variables which are modified inside a loop. The first step is to add `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` somwhere at teh beginning of your code. The second step is to access the variables which are modified inside the loop with `!varname!` instead of `%varname%`. In your case it would be something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
...
set /a n=!n!+1
echo Pinging : 10.0.0.!n!
ping 10.0.0.!n!
if !n! lss 255 goto doitagain
...
```