# Batch file :: if LSS not working as expected

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following script I have cobbled together to help with backups for Autodesk Vault Professional:

```
    @echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo setting up variables...
SET VAULTBACKUPPATH=C:\Users\alex.fielder\Dropbox\Graitec\Vault Backup
SET LOGFILEPATH=C:\Users\alex.fielder\Dropbox\Graitec\GRA0387AF_Vault_Backup.txt
SET SEVENZIPLOGFILEPATH=C:\Users\alex.fielder\Dropbox\Graitec\GRA0387AF_Zip_Log.txt
SET SEVENZIPPATH=C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\7za.exe
SET ADMSCONSOLEPATH=C:\Program Files\Autodesk\ADMS Professional 2017\ADMS Console\Connectivity.ADMSConsole.exe
SET NUMDAYSBACKUPTOKEEP=-15
SET MINMEMVALUE=2000000
SET MINDRIVESPACE=10000000
echo testing available system resources
for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic os get freephysicalmemory') do (SET AVAILABLESYSTEMMEMORY=%%p)
rem echo "%AVAILABLESYSTEMMEMORY%"
if !AVAILABLESYSTEMMEMORY! LSS %MINMEMVALUE% (
    echo "%DATE% %TIME%: low available system memory, exiting" >> %LOGFILEPATH%
    exit /b 1
) ELSE (
    echo "%DATE% %TIME%: sufficient system memory, continuing" >> %LOGFILEPATH%
)
echo checking free disk space on C:\
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3" %%s IN (`DIR C:\ /-C /-O /W`) DO (
    SET FREE_SPACE=%%s
)
if !FREE_SPACE! LSS !MINDRIVESPACE! (
    echo "%DATE% %TIME%: low space on C:, exiting" >> %LOGFILEPATH%
    exit /b 1
) ELSE (
    echo "%DATE% %TIME%: sufficient space on C:\, continuing" >> %LOGFILEPATH%
)
REM echo stopping and disabling Sophos
REM wmic service where "caption like 'Sophos%%'" call Stopservice
REM wmic service where "caption like 'Sophos%%' and  Startmode<>'Disabled'" call ChangeStartmode Disabled
echo pausing Dropbox, Searchindexer, Everything using the sysinternals tool PSSuspend!
pssuspend dropbox
pssuspend searchindexer
pssuspend everything


echo changing to working folder
cd "C:\Users\alex.fielder\Dropbox\Graitec\Vault Backup"
echo removing existing backup directories if there are any present
for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /b Vault*') do rd /s /q %%i
echo performing vault backup from Vault Professional 2017
REM -WA is short for Windows Authentication - does not work with Vault basic!
call "%ADMSCONSOLEPATH%" -Obackup -B"%VAULTBACKUPPATH%" -WA -VAL -DBSC -S -L"%LOGFILEPATH%"

echo Beginning zip and verification using 7zip %date% - %time% >> "%SEVENZIPLOGFILEPATH%"
for /f "Tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /a:d /b Vault*') do (
echo creating a .7z archive of latest backup using the 7zip command line.
call "%SEVENZIPPATH%" a -t7z "%%i.7z" "%%i" -mmt -mx1
echo testing the archive - results can be found in the Vault backup log file!
call "%SEVENZIPPATH%" t "%%i.7z" -mmt -r >> "%SEVENZIPLOGFILEPATH%"
)
echo completed zip and verification using 7zip %date% - %time% >> "%SEVENZIPLOGFILEPATH%"

REM for /f "Tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b Vault*.7z') do call "%SEVENZIPPATH%" t "%%i" -mmt -r >> "%SEVENZIPLOGFILEPATH%"

echo removing backup directory to prevent Dropbox syncing it to the cloud.
for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /b Vault*') do rd /s /q %%i
echo removing backups older than 30 days to prevent Dropbox space getting eaten up unecessarily.
forfiles /p "%VAULTBACKUPPATH%" /s /m *.* /d "%NUMDAYSBACKUPTOKEEP%" /c "cmd /c del @path"
echo resuming Dropbox, Searchindexer, Everything and Sophos
pssuspend -r dropbox
pssuspend -r searchindexer
pssuspend -r everything
REM wmic service where "caption like 'Sophos%%' and Startmode='Disabled'" call ChangeStartmode Automatic
REM wmic service where "caption like 'Sophos%%'" call Startservice
echo finished!
```

All of this was working fine except I added this section to check system resources/space on C: Drive and I can't get the syntax correct for it:

```
    echo testing available system resources
for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic os get freephysicalmemory') do (SET AVAILABLESYSTEMMEMORY=%%p)
rem echo "%AVAILABLESYSTEMMEMORY%"
if !AVAILABLESYSTEMMEMORY! LSS %MINMEMVALUE% (
    echo "%DATE% %TIME%: low available system memory, exiting" >> %LOGFILEPATH%
    exit /b 1
) ELSE (
    echo "%DATE% %TIME%: sufficient system memory, continuing" >> %LOGFILEPATH%
)
echo checking free disk space on C:\
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3" %%s IN (`DIR C:\ /-C /-O /W`) DO (
    SET FREE_SPACE=%%s
)
if !FREE_SPACE! LSS !MINDRIVESPACE! (
    echo "%DATE% %TIME%: low space on C:, exiting" >> %LOGFILEPATH%
    exit /b 1
) ELSE (
    echo "%DATE% %TIME%: sufficient space on C:\, continuing" >> %LOGFILEPATH%
)
```

Can anyone offer any pointers as to how I might correct this?

I did find this post:

[Batch file :: if lss is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366300/batch-file-if-lss-is-not-working-properly)

but as you can see above, I've tried several different variations and none have worked successfully.

Thanks,

Alex.

Comment: Are the numbers you are comparing signed 32-bit integers, or are they possibly too huge?

Comment: If so, pad each with 20 leading zeroes, and compare the last 20 characters of the two resultant strings, quoting each to ensure you force an alphabetic comparison.

Comment: @aschipfl: I'm not sure what you mean? the numbers are stored in the variables near the top of the script i.e: SET MINMEMVALUE=2000000
SET MINDRIVESPACE=10000000

Comment: @Magoo: I'm trying to see if the available system memory is greater than a set value, not a string comparison.

Comment: But what about `FREE_SPACE`? batch can only handle integers in the range [-2^31,2^31-1], so [-2147483648,2147483647]...

Comment: Hi @aschipfl I don't think that's a problem as the free space value could not ever reach that high; the C: drive in this case is only 500GB and the value returned is in kb. As it happens, I commented out the system memory section and the rest works fine.

Comment: Would it be possible to tell us what the value returned as system memory was?

Comment: `dir` usually returns the free space in terms of Bytes but not KBytes...

Comment: Compo very kindly provided a working alternative, but since you asked here  is what the wmic command returns: "wmic os get freephysicalmemory
FreePhysicalMemory
2550756" i.e. 2.5GB

Comment: Ah - so it was the `if !FREE_SPACE! LSS !MINDRIVESPACE! (` that was causing the problem? The fix there is to prepend a string of 20 `0`s to each of `FREE_SPACE` and `MINDRIVESPACE` then use `if "%free_space_with_zeroes:~-20%" lss "%mindrivespace:~-20%"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a different approach and let WMI determine if below your minimum values.

```bat
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Setting up variables...

SET "LOGFILEPATH=C:\Users\alex.fielder\Dropbox\Graitec\GRA0387AF_Vault_Backup.txt"
SET "MINMEMVALUE=2000000"
SET "MINDRIVESPACE=10000000"

ECHO Testing available system resources

ECHO Checking free system memory
SET "FPM=sufficient system memory, continuing"
FOR /F "USEBACKQ EOL=F" %%A IN (`WMIC OS WHERE^
 "FreePhysicalMemory < '%MINMEMVALUE%'" GET FreePhysicalMemory 2^>NUL`
) DO FOR %%B IN (%%A) DO SET "FPM=%%B"
IF NOT "%FPM%"=="sufficient system memory, continuing" (
    SET "FPM=low available system memory, exiting")
ECHO "%DATE% %TIME%: %FPM%">>"%LOGFILEPATH%"

ECHO Checking free system drive space
SET "SFP=sufficient space on %SystemDrive%, continuing"
FOR /F "USEBACKQ EOL=F" %%A IN (`WMIC LOGICALDISK WHERE^
     "DeviceID = '%SystemDrive%' AND FreeSpace < '%MINDRIVESPACE%'"^
     GET FreeSpace 2^>NUL`) DO FOR %%B IN (%%A) DO SET "SFP=%%B"
IF NOT "%SFP%"=="sufficient space on %SystemDrive%, continuing" (
    SET "SFP=low space on %SystemDrive%, exiting")
ECHO "%DATE% %TIME%: %SFP%">>"%LOGFILEPATH%"

PAUSE
```

Comment: That's great Compo, Thank you very much!